# Segfault code 11 at build time probably caused by Objective-C Singleton in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audio, the-amazing-audio-engine

I'm making a Swift iOS app that play an audio file and I'm using The Amazing Audio Engine 2 library for that.

I decided to use the Singleton pattern to manage this task. In his Swift sample project, Michael Tyson, the creator of the lib, did his audio part in Objective-C (for memory management stuff with C functions if I good understand).
You can find his explanation video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZQT4IGS8mA
So I followed his lead and I coded my Singleton in Objective-C.

Here is my code :

AudioManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine.h"

@class Track;

@interface AudioManager : NSObject {
    NSString *test;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) AEAudioUnitOutput  *_Nonnull output;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AERenderer *_Nonnull renderer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AEAudioFilePlayerModule *_Nullable currentTrackModule;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL recording;
@property (nonatomic) Track *_Nullable currentTrack;

+ (_Nonnull id)defaultAudioManager;
- (BOOL)startAudioController:(NSError *_Nullable *_Nullable)error;
- (void)stopAudioController;
- (void)prepareTrackModule;
- (void)playCurrentTrack:(BOOL)loop;

@end
```

AudioManager.m

```
#import "AudioManager.h"
#import "Project-Swift.h"
@import AVFoundation;

@implementation AudioManager

//@synthesize someProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)defaultAudioManager {
    static AudioManager *defaultAudioManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultAudioManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return defaultAudioManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if ( !(self = [super init]) ) return nil;
    //someProperty = @"Default Property Value";
    self.renderer = [AERenderer new];
    self.output = [[AEAudioUnitOutput alloc] initWithRenderer:self.renderer];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
}

- (BOOL)startAudioController:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];

    return [self.output start:error];
}

- (void)stopAudioController {
    return [self.output stop];
}

- (void)prepareTrackModule {
    self.currentTrackModule = [[AEAudioFilePlayerModule alloc] initWithRenderer:self.renderer
                                                  URL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                       URLForResource:@"amen"//self.currentTrack.name
                                                       withExtension:@"m4a"]
                                                error:NULL];
}

- (void)playCurrentTrack:(BOOL)loop {
    self.currentTrackModule.loop = loop;
    [self.currentTrackModule playAtTime:0];
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.renderer.block = ^(const AERenderContext *context) {
        AEModuleProcess(weakSelf.currentTrackModule, context);

        AEBufferStackMixToBufferList(context->stack, 1, 0, YES, context->output);
    };
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.Swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        do {
            try AudioManager.defaultAudioManager().startAudioController()
            //AudioManager.defaultAudioManager().prepareTrackModule()
            //AudioManager.defaultAudioManager().playCurrentTrack(true)
        } catch {
            //Handle Error
            print("error")
        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }
}
```

If I comment the line `try AudioManager.defaultAudioManager().startAudioController()` in my `AppDelegate.swift` file, obviously everything works, otherwise, Xcode print me this non very helpful error when I try to compile :

```
0  swift                    0x000000010411d4eb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010411c7d6 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 70
2  swift                    0x000000010411db4f SignalHandler(int) + 287
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9a64352a _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000001 _sigtramp + 1704708849
5  swift                    0x0000000101fba410 (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 2736
6  swift                    0x0000000101fa7c4b swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9787
7  swift                    0x0000000101f02fd8 swift::irgen::IRGenModuleDispatcher::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 600
8  swift                    0x0000000101f8ea5e performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1278
9  swift                    0x0000000101f8ef06 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 70
10 swift                    0x0000000101e72a1c performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 15004
11 swift                    0x0000000101e6e41d frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2781
12 swift                    0x0000000101e69e3c main + 1932
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff996215ad start + 1
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00000000000000bc start + 1721625360
Stack dump:
```

`Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

I think that I'm missing something in the Objective-C part that I don't understand, I'm not very familiar with this language, but I don't know what.
Any Idea ?

Comment: In startAudiocontroller func it accepts a NSError parameter and you have not passed any value to it. Even though it is nullable, swift doesn't go well with null values and it has to be explicit handled using if let or guard. Try to work around the NSError part and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @ArunGupta I'm not sure about what I have to do, I can't pass any argument to `startAudioController` in `appDelegate.swift` without Xcode printing the error `Cannot call value of non-function type '(() throws -> ())!'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, if I remove the parameters of the startAudioController function, the segfault disappear. I don't know why exactly but it can be a temporary solution